# Cannot execute <sequential> task with Ant

Tags: java, ant, java-7

Since I updated my Java from JDK7u55 to JDK7u60, I am facing an issue while running my build. I am using Ant 1.6.5 on Windows Server 2003 Standard Edition. Below is the Ant task which causes a problem.

```
<!-- RUN JUNIT TASK -->
<target name="run_junit" description="Runs all JUnit tests in another JVM">
    <sequential>
            <move file="${MyProject}\bin\myApp.jar" tofile="${MyProject}\bin\myApp_original.jar"/>
            <move file="${MyProject}\bin\myApp_test.jar" tofile="${MyProject}\bin\myApp.jar"/>

            <exec executable="WinTail" spawn="true">
                <arg value="${MyProject}\junit.log"/>
            </exec>

            <java classname="myProject.test.AllTests"
                maxmemory="256m"
                fork="true"
                output="${MyProject}\junit.log"
                dir="${MyProject}\bin"
                append="true">
            <jvmarg value="-Djdk.lang.Process.allowAmbigousCommands=true"/>
            <arg value="${MyProject}\bin"/>
            <classpath>
                <fileset dir="${MyProject}\bin">
                    <include name="myApp.jar"/>
                </fileset>
                <pathelement path="${MyProject}\bin"/>
            </classpath>
            </java>

            <move file="${MyProject}\bin\myApp.jar" tofile="${MyProject}\bin\myApp_test.jar"/>
            <move file="${MyProject}\bin\myApp_original.jar" tofile="${MyProject}\bin\myApp.jar"/>
    </sequential>
</target>
```

Once two JARs have been renamed, I start running all the tests using `<java>` task. The AllTests.java uses seperate thread to run each test. There are some tests which takes bit longer to finish and some actually don't respond. I used to kill them manually by using ProcessExplorer. Once that was done it used to execute next  command which renames back the JARs to their original names. It used to work when I was using JDK7u55.

Now since I upgraded Java to JDK7u60, instead of waiting for all the tests to be finished, the last two `<move>` commands are attempted. This causes the build failure as `<move>` caanot proceed because the underlying JAR files are being used by the test classes. I get below error:

> BUILD FAILED
>
> C:\MyProject\build.xml:579: Unable to delete file C:\MyProject\bin\myApp.jar

I am wondering what has changed in JDK7u60 which caused this behavior. I checked the Release Notes of JDK7u60 but didn't get anything. Can someone please shed some light on this?

Comment: is your jar App.jar in use by some other process? which is line 579 in your build.xml?

Comment: Line no 579 is the second last <move> command. As I said it doesn't wait for all the tests to be finished before executing line no. 579, the jar is being used by the tests.

Comment: doesn't that answer then?

Comment: I already wrote in my question that it works for earlier version of Java. Its not working when I upgrade my Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly on windows it's not uncommon for files belonging to another process or thread to prevent the deletion of a file.

Secondly what exactly is the purpose of the sequential task in your ANT target? The [documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sequential.html) describes the tasks as follows:

> Sequential is a container task - it can contain other Apache Ant
>   tasks. The nested tasks are simply executed in sequence. Sequential's
>   primary use is to support the sequential execution of a subset of
>   tasks within the parallel task

In your case there's no use of [parallel](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/parallel.html)...

Why don't you try to remove the sequential task and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: I need to execute those tasks sequentially. I should have put <sequential> tasks into <parallel>. But even after doing that I get same error. Yes, I understand the reason that since test classes would have used the jar when it tries to <move>, but then why the behavior is not same with JDK7u55? That is surprising.

Comment: @ParagJ I'm guessing that it has something like a difference in file handling by threads, buried deep within the JVM :-)